# Should I Abandon Adobe Flash for HTML5 and <canvas>?

Tags: php, facebook, actionscript, html

I'm currently looking into developing Facebook applications and was planning on using Flash as the basis of my application, I have test built some simple PHP Facebook applications and I know enough about action-script 3 to start me on my way, but the API for Facebook development in AS looks far more tedious than the PHP one.

my question is would I be able to create interactive graphics (games) like we see across the web in the HTML5 canvas class? and which would be simpler?

Comment: Steve Jobs apparently think you should abandon Flash ;)
http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2008/03/iphone-users-th/

Comment: Probably there might be an experimental canvas 2d game engine, but I doubt at this time there is anything that will suit your needs. 
At work I worked on a project using the Facebook API, and the as3 facebook api is a bit cumbersome, but not impossible to use. If you're happy using php, then I you could use that to handle all your facebook queries, and leave the client side(flash) as 'dumb' as possible, pass it only the data it needs.

Comment: If you are doing game development, maybe you should also take a look at Silverlight

Comment: I would if I wasn't so Anti-MS ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HTML5 doesn't truly exist yet outside of the basic support in the various browsers.  We're a couple of years off from true saturation since it won't be until IE9 and FF4 are released and then widely adopted.

You could use the Google Code project to enable canvas support in IE however until then:

http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/

And yes, you would be able to create some interesting games with canvas.  I do however believe in the short term you'd have a wider array of options with Flash.

http://www.canvasdemos.com/

Answer (score 4):

Flash will definitely be easier since it is mature and there are lots of game engines built for it. Canvas would work on iPhone, but many other browser versions don't support it.

I'd say it isn't quite ready for primetime yet.

Comment: Many? The only one that doesn't is IE.

Comment: Correction: IE and the various browsers that run on top of IE's "Trident" engine (Maxthon, Avant Browser, and so on).  In terms of desktop/notebook computers (Mac and PC both), the canvas element works for sure (except in IE-based browsers), but the actual canvas API support might vary.  As for mobile/mini UAs (e.g. Opera Mini, Mozilla Fennec, etc.), I'm really not sure about the support for canvas there.  I wouldn't be surprised if it was supported though.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to stick with Flash until html5 becomes a mature option and there's at least one robust IDE in the market.

Answer (score 3):

Canvas and SVG are new but it's ramping up fast and I'm seeing a lot of article/demos all over the place, including the right hand side of this page. Your only real problem might be that IE won't handle it and I don't recall if Microsoft said it would (adding even more to IE's demise on the web).

Comment: IE9 will support HTML5 and H.264 as *the* video standard.

Comment: We're talking canvas, not video. Microsoft may find it made a huge mistake, though.

Answer (score 2):

It totally depends on what you're doing. If the features you use in Flash are only those provided by HTML5, the you probably should. Otherwise you just can't.

Here are some of my thoughts in response to similar questions:

- [should web developers learn flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643407/should-web-developers-learn-flash/2644910#2644910)
- [Does HTML5 only replace the video aspects of Flash/Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681411/does-html5-only-replace-the-video-aspects-of-flash-silverlight/2682865#2682865)

greetz
back2dos

Answer (score 2):

Not yet. I would port all the site to HTML5 keeping the old flash version, just using one or other version checking which navigator is accessing the page.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you would want to do. I don't agree with the person who said HTML5 does not exist yet. Technically IE doesn't support it yet, but there are workarounds for that.

There are already a lot of applications/games built using HTML5 which are live.

HTML5 does not support Audio/video capture yet. So, if you think that you won't be needing that, you can go with HTML5. I'm sure there are other advantages and disadvantages on both sides.

Also, HTML5 is free so...

Apple on the other hand has issues with Adobe, and they don't support Flash in iphone/ipad. So, depending on who wins that battle, things will be a lot different.

Hope that helps,
-Roozbeh

Answer (score 1):

There're always two sides... On the one hand HTML5 is faster and (isn't going to) require any additional plugins. But it looks like that HTML5 isn't going to be fully implemented earlier than in 2018 to 2020. Until then you have to use other plugins or addins...


As for Flash...It's for now nearly the best practice you can use for RIAs. You can implement 3d, video, MP3s and so on and so on. So I would say Flash is the best technology at this moment. But it's on you to decide xD


P.S. Look at all this facebook apps... only flash...

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this case lately as well,

Current standards suggest, like Steve Job's vision.

Adobe Flash is starting to show it's age.

Reasons:

Boost of the mobile market, more people viewing website content on mobile devices and tablets.

HTML5 JavaScript and WebGL seems to be the way of the future.
Here are some of the facts.

WebGL has really taken off in recent years. 
with a massive extension to application support.

e.g. Unity 3d, IOS, Android OS and all the major web browser markets.

JavaScript, is making some massive strides though-out the web community and even expending into the desktop market with products like Google's Chrome OS.

HTML 5 can cater for video content playing on all browsers and other awesome elements.

From a network support stand point.

Adobe has always been under fire for security risks that can cause issues with windows and other OS devices.

With these points in mind,

If a client doesn't specifically express they need to use Adobe Flash, I will opt for HTML5/JavaScript and WebGL over Adobe Flash, mainly to extend accessibility of the application.

Personally, I get so sick of updating flash players on the clients side.
This can be really frustrating when a client is trying to access your content.

Hope this helps others in their choose on "too Flash or not too Flash" your application.