# Very Basic Flash Animation Issues, Please Help!

Tags: flash, actionscript, animation

[image]
(1) How does flash animation work? What's the difference between flash animation and pure JavaScript animation? And I heard about HTML5?

(2) How does external action-script files (*.as) work? how do they work together along with .fla file to make the final swf file?

I have some basic understanding of HTML/CSS/JAVASCRIPT/XML stuff, but I want a little bit more detailed explanation with some very simple and intuitive example is highly appreciated!!

Noted with thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Animation in Flash can either be done in a visual click-and-drag way using the Timeline or by writing ActionScript to move the objects, whereas animation in JavaScript has to be written in code.

2) Flash combines graphics from the .fla with code from .as to create the swf. This process is often referred to as "compiling the swf" but note that it is very different from compiling C code.

Comment: But can I have a preview of the final outcome with .fla file along with .as files(instead of swf)? Because when I open the fla file(sits in the same folder with other as files) shown in picture theres basically nothing to see?

Comment: You can view timeline animations within Flash but the code only runs when compiled into a swf. If you have all the code then just Test Movie to compile.

Answer (score 0):

These Would help :

[html5 vs flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628565/html5-vs-flash-full-comparison-chart-anywhere)

[Javascript vs Flash](http://logicpool.com/archives/30)

Remember Html5 needs Javascript for its key and extra features. so you can not compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Flash animation, that is not done in AS3, is done with keyframes and tweening. It also has a great vector engine for graphics.