# Is html/javascript equivalent to as3/flex?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, html

Hello my fellow coders,

As i notice for a while now (like everybody else in the industry), the RIA market is shifting from AS3/Flex to HTML/Javascript.
What i would like to know is? Is html/javascript as powerfull as as3/Flex or are they entirely different. With other words can i build the exact same applictions with HTML(4/5) and Javascript as i can do with AS3/Flex?

I'm not looking for the speed comparison? or bashing one technology over the other?
I just want to know if is good for me to dive into javascript, JQuery......

PS. If there is a nother post on stackoverflow with the exacte question. please share the link. Thanks.

Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628565/html5-vs-flash-full-comparison-chart-anywhere

Answer (score 3):

> can i build the exact same applictions with HTML(4/5) and Javascript
>   as i can do with AS3/Flex?

definitely NO, and this will be true for quite a while...

> is good for me to dive into javascript, JQuery

yes. always good to learn something new and your as3 skills will get you there quickly

Answer (score 0):

I think diving into JS HTML5 is never a bad idea. Hell I know a couple of hardcore as3/flex/flash people who totally uninstalled adobe off their machines. However I think Adobe will find a way to make its software relevant in other ways or even maybe integrate it into html5 and JS somehow. So to answer your question, Yes learn JS/html5 but keep your eye on new developments in as3/flex

Answer (score -4):

JavaScript over **HTML5** is (or soon will be) the most powerful scripting language there is. HTML5 is not yet implemented in all browsers but it will be. When this happens probably there will be no point in using any of the famous plugins like Flash because with such things like [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), [Canvas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element) and [Video](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video) and much more you can do everything in JavaScript.

So learning JavaScript (with jQuery and many other interesting libraries) is the most important thing you can do imho. There's even more! JavaScript is entering the server-side (for example [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs)). The future of web development in my opinion!

Comment: I agree. The *future*, however far off that may be!

Comment: I think you have a very limited view of the world if you think JavaScript over HTML5 will be the most powerful scripting language.  If you put that into context of "inside browsers"; you may be able to make an argument; but a world of programming exists well beyond browser based applications.

Comment: Eh, isn't this obvious that the context of both question and the answer is: browsers? I'm quite sure that JavaScript is not well suited for programming spying robots or satelites.

Comment: @freakish It is not obvious to me that the context is "Browsers".  Flex (And ActionScript) can be used to build desktop applications on Windows and MAC and Native mobile applications for iOS, Android, and Blackberry.  I understand similar  options exist when using HTML/JavaScript.  Sencha Touch comes to mind as one option for building native mobile apps w/ HTML/JS.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com If someone is actually using HTML/JS as a part of desktop applications (which sounds like a browser to me) then I'd still claim that JS beats ActionScript/Flex/whatever.

Comment: @freakish Many web browser are desktop applications, however I do not know of any browser written in HTML and JavaScript.  You are more than welcome to think JS beats ActionScript; I do not think they can be compared easily. They solve different purposes.